# Number of quadrilaterals formed out of N points.

Tags: combinations, polygons, quadrilateral, convex-geometry

How can I calculate the number of $4$-vertex convex polygons (quadrilaterals) that can be formed out of $n$ given points, where $n \geq 4$?

Note: Points can be collinear. So triangles with $3$ sides but $4$ vertices are also allowed.

Comment: Do you mean with $n$ given points, or the maximum number with any $n$ points?

Comment: @RobertIsrael with n given points

Comment: What about when all 4 points are colinear, so you have a totally flat quadrilateral?  Also, are the $n$ points in the plane?

Comment: Even with 4 points it depends on the disposition of the points

Comment: @BobbyGrizzard No, only the polygons with 4 vertices are counted. They can't be flat quadrilaterals! All the points are on a plane!

Comment: I'm talking about e.g. a "quadrilateral" whose vertices were 1, 2, 3, and 4 (all on the $x$-axis), and the four edges are [1,3], [3,4], [4,2], and [2,1].  This has four vertices and is convex.  Does it count?

Comment: @BobbyGrizzard No, this can't be counted!

Comment: @BobbyGrizzard Doing some little research it seems it is a type of convex hull problem?

Comment: Right... each convex quadrilateral as you describe is formed by choosing three points which are not colinear, and then a fourth point which is not in the interior of the convex hull of the first three.

Comment: ... except that none of the original three can be in the interior of the convex hull of the others.  If you think of the sides of the triangle formed by the original three as opaque, only two of the vertices of this triangle can be visible from the fourth  point.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please point me to some article regarding the subject?